# Datatype used to send string value + url

Tags: sql, database, sqldatatypes

In My application I have to post data on database.I am using querystring to post my data.Also I am using String datatype on database.
But My data is some String value with url >>(e.g Ho! Download kijiye Salman ki Aanewali Blockbuster Jai Ho Ki Superhit Caller Tunes. T&C apply. RCOM. Click

> > Url:http://bit.ly/19CtoVp&date=01/18/2014).
> >     Now How can I post my data on database.Is there Anyother datatype which can store string value with url in SQL.Suggest me Please......

Answer (score 1):

The best datatype to use in that kind of situation is still String because you're dealing with random characters including special, numerical and non-numerical. Do remember to use anti-SQL injection functions especially when values have quotes in it.

```
There are basically only 4 most commonly used datatypes in a database.
1) String - Stores any value found on the ASCII Table.
2) Float - Store numbers.
3) Date/Time - Stores date and time.
4) Binary - Stores anything in binary form such as pictures, videos, mp3, virtually anything in binary form.
```

Of course there are variations for each datatype, like float and integer, the difference is the alloted bytes for it. Float can store bigger numbers so you can use float instead to be safe.

Comment: Is any datatype that can store both string and url

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean can String store both string and URL values, then yes, String can store any value within the ASCII Table :)

Comment: But In case of using queryString....the http of url of msg clashes with the http of querystring.so data is not posting

Comment: So I want to ask If any other datatype other than string that can store both string and url

Comment: You technically can convert the URL into binary form and store it in the database, but that would mean you'll have to convert everything into binary first and store, and convert it back to characters from binary every time you want to use it. If you don't want this, then NOPE, there is no other way. What do you mean clashes with the http of querystring by the way? Can you give a scenario?

Comment: http://115.254.99.27/MobileApi/WebPage.aspx?func=msg&ImeiNo=355294050982396&ph=RM-651234&msg=Jai Ho! Download kijiye Salman ki Aanewali Blockbuster Jai Ho Ki Superhit Caller Tunes. T&C apply. RCOM. Click 
 Url:http://bit.ly/19CtoVp&date=01/18/2014&cType=1
I m passing this value....

Comment: So you want to store http://115.254.99.27/MobileApi/WebPage.aspx?func=msg&ImeiNo=355294050982396&ph=RM-651234&msg=Jai this into the database? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Actually In this there is two http 1.of querystring 2.of url of message.....these two http in same querystring url creates problem and don't let data to post on database

Comment: Can you post the error message when posting? What database are you using?

Comment: Sql database....It doesn't post on database .showing error here.HttpResponse response = httpc.execute(post);
   if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) .I am using this code in android application

Comment: Can you try to execute query directly against the database using SQL view on database? Your error message doesn't indicate anything specific. You have to get the specific error. Your error just gets the status of the SQL execution if it succeeded or not.

Comment: In My queryString If I pass only String value and ommit the url value of Msg body then It is posting correctly.But not with the url...Also I have used String datatype in sql table

Comment: I tried inserting the values, it works fine on my side. I'm using SQL server. Can you be more specific? I really don't understand the part where you say the URL did not post, but it posted fine without the URL.

Comment: yes Boss .........sorry for Interruption....Actually error occurs if we pass this value also.---->>Hello!!!!!!!!!!@123..........By Barun Kumar..My no. is 9039579755/9015238253
-
 Reply via way2sms.com. Now available on your mobile

Comment: I inserted this value  - Hello!!!!!!!!!!@123..........By Barun Kumar..My no. is 9039579755/9015238253 - Reply via way2sms.com. Now available on your mobile - and it still works on my side. My datatype is nvarchar(255)

Comment: I am using varchar(500)...Is it due to which data is not posting

Comment: Try changing the datatype to nvarchar(MAX) and see if it works.

Comment: I have done this But It also can't works........I have done my coding this way http://pastie.org/8650146

Comment: Hmmm, try showing finalURL2 visually before you insert this into the database. Pop it out in a message box or whatever. Check the string if everything is okay. Does finalURL2 contain any single quote?

Comment: yes I am getting the finalurl2 correctly.the latest one is http://115.254.99.27/MobileApi/WebPage.aspx?func=msg&ImeiNo=355294050982396&ph=RM-651234&msg=Salman Khan ki dhamakedar geeton ko kahiye Jai Ho aur Ban Jaaiye Salman Khan Ki Super Fan. T&C apply. RCOM. Click 
 Url:http://bit.ly/1cnSwJz&date=01/20/2014&cType=1 
Everything seems fine

Comment: Hmmm, your code is very limited to be troubleshooted. Please do check the API you're using if it really executes the right SQL statement.

Comment: if I send a simple" hello " msg from my phone.it correctly post the data But if I use any other different special character and numbers it is not posted........can't understand the reason

Comment: Hmmmmm, I understand your confusion. I've experienced something like this before too. This is usually not an issue but better check everything now down to the last detail. Can you try to INSERT the data into the database without using JAVA to interact with the API first? INSERT it directly using management studio.

Comment: yes I have used this querystring url and post it in browser url place to hit and it is posted well on db.then why not through my app code.

Comment: Hmmmmm, can you edit your question and post your code so everybody can see? I'd like to help you do this but the code you gave me was very limited. You'll have to post more of the code so we can check everything. Was that everything already? I didn't think so.